# Stop previous events on mousleave

Tags: ajax, jquery

On mouseenter I make an AJAX request to get some dynamic text based on the title attribute of the hovered href and show it in another div.

It's a list of links and when I hover over them very fast, all ajax requests are finished and all text is shown one after another very quick until the current text shows up.

How can I **stop previously called requests and prevent every text to show up** in my div?

This is what I've got so far:

```
$('.link').mouseenter(function(e) {

var text = $(this).attr('title');

$('#showtext').show().html('Loading...');

    $.ajax({
    url: '/show.php?text=' + text,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#showtext').html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $('#showtext').html('Error.');
    }
    });

});

$('.link').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#showtext').hide();
}
```

I tried to use `.stopPropagation()` and `.preventDefault()` on mouseenter and mouseleave and also `.abort()`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex's solution is sufficient, but does not abort slow requests.  Also, I avoid plugins for trivial things like timeout.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkxZ5/3/)

```
(function($) {
    var request;
    $('.link').bind('updatetext', function() {
        var text = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#showtext').show().html('Loading...');
        request = $.ajax({
            url: '/show.php?text=' + text
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#showtext').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#showtext').html('Error finding ' + text);
            }
        });
    });
    var timeout;
    $('.link').mouseenter(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).trigger('updatetext')
        }, 500);
    });
    $('.link').mouseleave(function() {
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
            request = null;
        }
        $('#showtext').hide();
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 1):

Aborting the request should work like that:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    url: '/show.php?text=' + text,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#showtext').html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        $('#showtext').html('Error.');
    }
});
//abort
req.abort()
```

What if you use hover instead of mouseenter and mouseleave? Of course you'll get a similar problem. If you hover too fast, everything will be loaded.
Because of that, I suggest you the [hoverIntent jQuery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). The `hoverIntent` event is only called if the mouse rests for some seconds (changeable) on the target element.
Your code would kinda look like this:

```
$('.link').hoverIntent(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#showtext').show().html('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/show.php?text=' + text,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#showtext').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $('#showtext').html('Error.');
        }
    });
},function(e){
    $('#showtext').hide();    
});
```

Because the event is only fired when you **really want**, there should never be too many AJAX-Requests.

Comment: I already tried abort() but I get an "can't find variable req" error when using on mouseleave..

Comment: initialize an array or a variable **outside from the events** and then add the requests inside the `mouseenter`-event.